# Sprite not adding to group to display on screen

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite, render

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/Pcprojects/pygameKCC/kcc-shmup.py", line 49, in 
    all_sprites.update()

### TypeError: unbound method update() must be called with Group instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

I'm following a tutorial that has working code (for him), and for my life I can't get this sprite to render. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is my first time with sprites other than a basic bouncy ball screen saver type thing. Thanks!

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
import math

#global constants
WIDTH = 360
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30

#define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
#YELLOW = (X, X, X)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #sprite for the player.
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #required image and collision rectangle
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)

#itialize pygame
#itialize music mixer
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

#create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#create a group for all sprites to belong to
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)


running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

#updated:

```
    all_sprites.update()
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: after drawing sprites you `fill()` screen - this way you remove all sprites before you send them from buffer on monitor (using `flip()`). You have to first `fill()`, next `draw()` and later use `flip()` to send buffer on monitor.

Comment: I run code and I don't get this error.

Comment: for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #game Exit on [x] click
    #Update
    all_sprites.update()
    #Render/Draw
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

here is the excerpt that i moved around, but I'm still getting the same error. Could it be a pycharm issue?_eta: I can't figure out how you format code in a comment sorry!

Comment: add this in question - it will be more readable and everyone will read it.

Comment: and add full error message (Traceback). There can be more usefull information.

Comment: if you think it is problem with PyCharm then run code outside PyCharm - `python script.py` - and you will see if you are right.

Comment: it was a pycharm issue, thanks so much! Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

You have to first clear screen using `fill()` and later draw sprites - `draw()`. And after that you can send buffer on monitor - `flip()`

```
#Render/Draw
screen.fill(BLACK)
all_sprites.draw(screen)
pygame.display.flip()
```

---

BTW: to center element on `screen` you can use

```
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
```

and later

```
 self.rect.center = screen_rect.center
```

The same way you can center other things - ie. text on button.